# Leer Archivo .txt separados por coma

Tags: vb.net, datatable, split

Por ayuda necesito pasar estas lenas separadas por coma a un datatable.

estas son las lineas. al final de la linea también la separación es una por coma.

```
000000000000056680640,07/07/2016,1606169715409,000000933.00,DB,EXI IB INFOTEP 501606169715409  RD$.00,409,0000000000000,
000000000000056680640,08/07/2016,0000000000004,000000044.02,DB,PAGO IMPUESTO 0.15  DGII 4 TRANS POR $ 29348.29 Del 01/07/2016 Al 07/07/2016,524,0000000000000,
000000000000056680640,11/07/2016,0000777517509,000007000.00,CR,IB MB desde 777517509 ,201,0000000000000,
000000000000056680640,13/07/2016,0000120000002,000050490.00,CR,DEPOSITO CHEQUE Y EFECTIVO,108,0000120000002,
000000000000056680640,13/07/2016,0160438491157,000008564.40,DB,EXI IB DGII 160438491157  RD$.00,409,0000000000000,
000000000000056680640,13/07/2016,0000000000000,000000075.00,DB,COMISION PAGO IMPUESTO X IB  RD$.00,524,0000000000000,
000000000000056680640,13/07/2016,0003579084854,000001851.27,DB,EXI IB DGII 3579084854  RD$.00,409,0000000000000,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalmente hay un *problema* con los *archivos separados por comas*, y es que es un formato que no está estandarizado, y diferentes personas (y sistemas) asumen cosas diferentes en los detalles.

En palabras del artículo [Comma-separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) de la [Wikipedia en inglés](http://en.wikipedia.org), traducido libremente:

> El formato de archivo CSV no está estandarizado. La idea básica de separar campos con una coma es clara, pero esa idea se complica cuando los datos de los campos a su vez contienen comas o, incluso, terminaciones de línea.
>
> Diferentes implementaciones CSV pueden no soportar dichos datos en los campos, o pueden utilizar comillas para encerrar un campo. Las comillas no resuelven todo: Algunos campos podrían contener también comillas, así que ciertas implementaciones CSV podrían incluir caracteres o secuencias de escape.

En general mi recomendación es hacer una implementación robusta en cualquier sistema, lo cuál en el futuro te ahorrará sonrojos y dolores de cabeza. Por fortuna, no tienes por qué escribir el código que se encarga de los detalles.

Puedes basarte, por ejemplo, en la clase [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Un pequeño ejemplo de uso podría ser:

```
Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.
    TextFieldParser("c:\logs\bigfile")

    MyReader.TextFieldType = 
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
    MyReader.CommentTokens = New String() {""}
    MyReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
    Dim currentRow As String()
    'Loop through all of the fields in the file. 
    'If any lines are corrupt, report an error and continue parsing. 
    While Not MyReader.EndOfData
        Try
            currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()

            Dim newRow = dTable.Rows.Add()
            newRow.ItemArray = currentRow

        Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
            MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & 
            " is invalid.  Skipping")
        End Try
    End While
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes encontrar un ejemplo en la [documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6.aspx), y es importante saber que por convención un archivo [.CSV (Comma separated value)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) debe tener esta estructura para sea considerado como tal:

```
a, Elenasys , 12345
b, Ronnie, 12345
c, Doru, 534543
d, Hassan, 6234234
e, Haris K., 78345345
```

Este sería un ejemplo de como convertir los valores obtenidos de un .csv a DataTable

```
    Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\path\archivo.csv")
    Dim dTable = New DataTable
    Dim numeroColumnas = lines.First.Split(","c).Length
    For i As Int32 = 1 To numeroColumnas
        'Agrega columnas a DataTable.
        dTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Columna_" & i, GetType(String)))
        Debug.Print("Columna_" & i)
    Next

    '**********************
    For Each line In lines
        Dim objFields = From field In line.Split(","c)
        Dim newRow = dTable.Rows.Add()
        newRow.ItemArray = objFields.ToArray()
        Debug.Print("columna_1: " & objFields.ToArray().GetValue(0).ToString)
        Debug.Print("columna_2: " & objFields.ToArray().GetValue(1).ToString)
        Debug.Print("columna_3: " & objFields.ToArray().GetValue(2).ToString)
    Next

    Debug.Print("finaliza!")
```

Comment: muchas gracias @Elenasys por tu respuesta acabo de probar tu ejemplo y me funcionó perfectamente

Comment: Esta respuesta es correcta si se sabe que el CSV es _simple_, para una implementación más robusta, mira [mi respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/21135/21) a esta misma pregunta.